# Reshaping nested array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I currently have an ndarray of shape (27,) where each array entry is an array of shape (121,61). I'd like to reshape the ndarray to a new size of (3267, 61), which is just expanding/flattening the nested arrays into one.

I've tried using the .resize(3267, 61) and .reshape(3267, 61) but when I do, the following error appears:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 27 into shape (3267, 61)

ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data

Comment: You need  the `reshape` function, not `resize`.

Comment: It will be easier for other to help you if you provide an example that reproduces the error you're seeing. You could generate a sample array using, e.g., `np.random.rand(shape)` (or whatever works for your context).

Comment: @joanis I tried the reshape function as you mentioned and it didn't work - see above

Comment: How about `np.reshape(array, (3267, 61))`? The numpy documentation says something about arrays that can be reshaped in place and others that cannot: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: @joanis didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array elements are indeed other 1D `nDarray` (as @CamiloMartínez showed it can happen), then use:

```py
b = np.concatenate(a)
```

If instead the array is just a 3D array (e.g. obtained by putting together a list of arrays and letting `numpy` optimize it), then use:

```py
b = a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1])
```

**General case**: If you are unsure, then the following works in either case. It also works in the case where `a` is a 2D (or higher dimensions) array containing arrays (as @drod31 was asking in the comments):

```py
b = np.stack(a.ravel())
b = b.reshape(-1, b.shape[-1])
```

Here is a minimal example:

case 1: (thx @CamiloMartínez for the setup).

```py
a = np.empty((27,), dtype=object)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i] = np.zeros((121, 61))

b = np.concatenate(a)
>>> b.shape
(3267, 61)
```

case 2 (my initial setup, that missed the actual array of array condition):

```py
a = np.array([np.zeros((121, 61)) for _ in range(27)])

b = a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1])

>>> b.shape
(3267, 61)
```

In any case, you'd usually like to express the transformation **without explicit hardcoded dimensions**, for more general use.

Corner-case example (as per @drod31 question):

```py
a = np.empty((15,27), dtype=object)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[i,j] = np.zeros((121, 61))

>>> a.shape
(15, 27)

>>> a[0,0].shape
(121, 61)

b = np.stack(a.ravel())
b = b.reshape(-1, b.shape[-1])

>>> b.shape
(49005, 61)
```

Comment: Should this also work for say a 2d array with shape size (15,27)? Where each array entry is (121, 61)

Comment: @Pierre D at least give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez: you are absolutely right: your example setup was important in understanding the question. Sorry about overlooking that.

Comment: @drod31: good point -- see modified answer to address that case too. It works with nd array as well (3d, 4d, ...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.stack()` to turn a sequence of arrays into a single `ndarray`, which can then be reshaped as you need:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((27,), dtype=object)
>>> for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    ... a[i] = np.zeros((121, 61))
>>> b = np.stack(a).reshape((27*121, 61))
>>> b.shape
    (3267, 61)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem I was having!

Comment: you can use `np.concatenate(a)`.

Comment: Indeed, `np.stack(a)` does the main trick! And @Pierre D is right. `np.concatenate(a)` does the `reshape` inmediately.

Comment: `np.concatenate` joins the component arrays along the existing first axis.  `np.stack` adds a new leading dimension, and then does the concatenate.